# Setting permissions for Flask Session in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, flask, uwsgi, flask-session

When building and running my custom Docker image for a Python Flask application that I am building, I get a permission error.:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/project/flask_session'

I have tried giving maximum permissions to the 'project' directory, as well as not setting the encompassing 'project' directory as a volume.

My image is generated from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libatlas-base-dev gfortran nginx supervisor

RUN pip3 install uwsgi

RUN mkdir project

COPY requirements.txt /project/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r /project/requirements.txt

RUN useradd --no-create-home nginx

ENV DATABASE_URI=postgres://mtcawriaieekfa:878c2c19e6524a72342de8943973871d1c6a88b77ee5c84b34a83458124e75da@ec2-54-75-230-41.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/db4jqtlpevbq8v

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN rm -r /root/.cache

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY flask-site-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi/
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/

COPY /app /project/app

WORKDIR /project

EXPOSE 5000:80

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Other errors seem to indicate that the lack of permissions is disallowing the folder 'project/flask_session' to be generated. I am using a framework called Flask Session, that generates the flask_session folder in my working directory in which user data is saved for a session. Thank you for in advance for any help or advice!

Comment: The VOLUME statement mostly only has confusing side effects and you should delete it.  If you're hiding the contents of the image with a `docker run -v` option or a Docker Compose `volumes:` option, that could cause this permissions problem; delete that setting.  Prefer two single-purpose containers to combining your application and a proxy server in one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you are onto something for sure. I updated the Dockerfile in the question definition and removed the volume stuff, but the error has persisted. I could try and create a compose or something to decouple the app and proxy server, but I would still need to learn a lot to do that...